# How to replace the repeat word in python (Hangman Game)!

Tags: python

This game now i have solved till the end.But here is 1 more problem that is how can i replace repeat word in string? please help me! Thank you. For example: my customfile inside there is word:"apple" and when hide the word with dashes: "-----" but when i replace in dashes string i can just only replace dash with 1 p:"ap-le" how can i replace dashes with 2p: "apple".My previous post for this program:[How do i detect the repeat input in my hangman game (Python)!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603184/how-do-i-detect-the-repeat-input-in-my-hangman-game-python/44605825?noredirect=1#comment76200806_44605825) . Here is my code to replace:

```
def getGuessedWord():
    pos = word.index(guessword.lower())
    print(pos)
    global words             
    words = words[:pos]+ guessword.lower() +words[pos+1:]
    print(words)
    return words
```

Comment: why can't you use `replace` ?

Comment: This question seems to be suffering from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Ravi cause i've tried to use replace but i don't know how to detect the position with method replace. so the word replace just appear again and again in the first position of dashes string.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to your overall problem of filtering out guessed letters is the following set of functions:

```
guessed_letters = set()
def guess(letter):
    global guessed_letters
    guessed_letters.add(letter)

def filter_letter(letter):
    if letter in guessed_letters:
        return letter
    else:
        return '-'

def filtered(words):
    for word in words:
        output = ''
        for letter in word:
            output += filter_letter(letter)
        yield output
```

or more compactly:

```
guessed_letters = set()
def guess(letter):
    global guessed_letters
    guessed_letters.add(letter)

def filter_letter(letter):
    return letter if letter in guessed_letters else '-'

def filtered(words):
    return [''.join(map(filter_letter, word)) for word in words]
```

such that:

```
>>> words = "bubbly water".split()
>>> guess('a')
>>> ' '.join(filtered(words))
'------ -a---'
>>> guess('b')
>>> ' '.join(filtered(words))
'b-bb-- -a---
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but can we combine them into 1 function i mean in 1 def and replace them in string of words ? Once again thank you so much !

Comment: In my method, i can just define 1 position of 1 p out of 2 p in word "apple". Do you have any solution for this? Thank you.

Comment: @VincentHoang I have made a [chatroom for this discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147004/q-44608020-7246614-discussion).

Comment: sorry i'm still a newbie and my reputation is just 11 so i cannot join in the discussion room :) .For example, i guess letters for the word " apple" my problem is that there are 2 p but when i key in the p it just only fill in the first p the second p cannot be filled in. :(. And  i've been asked to do this in 1 function.