# Instead of using global what to use for my situation in my hangman game (python)

Tags: python

i am wondering whether there is other way to solve my situation(replace user input(guessword) into dashes string(words) in my Hangman Game than to use global. My previous posts for the game: [How to replace the repeat word in python (Hangman Game)!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44608020/how-to-replace-the-repeat-word-in-python-hangman-game?noredirect=1#comment76203803_44608020) and [How do i detect the repeat input in my hangman game (Python)!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603184/how-do-i-detect-the-repeat-input-in-my-hangman-game-python/44605825?noredirect=1#comment76200806_44605825) and here is my code:
code from beginning:

```
def writeCustomwords():
    f = open('custom.txt', 'w')
    words = input("Enter a list of comma separated words:")
    print("Custom words save into custom.txt")
    f.write(words)
    f.close()
def readFileWords():
    if choose == "1":
        txt = open('easy.txt', 'r')
        txt.read()
        txt.close()


    elif choose == "2":
        txt = open('intermediate.txt', 'r')
        txt.read()
        txt.close()

    elif choose == "3":
        txt = open('hard.txt', 'r')
        txt.read()
        txt.close()

    elif choose == "4":
        txt = open('custom.txt', 'r')
        txt.read()
        txt.close()
import random
def getRandomWord():
    if choose == "1":
        with open('easy.txt') as txt:
            word = txt.read().splitlines()
        random_word = random.choice(word)
        print(random_word)
        print("\nThere are", len(random_word),"letters in this word")
    elif choose == "2":
        with open('intermediate.txt') as txt:
            word = txt.read().splitlines()
        random_word =  random.choice(word)

       print("\nThere are", len(random_word),"letters in this word")
    elif choose == "3":
        with open('hard.txt') as txt:
            word = txt.read().splitlines()
        random_word = random.choice(word)

        print("\nThere are", len(random_word),"letters in this word")
    elif choose == "4":
        with open('custom.txt') as txt:
            word = txt.read().split(",")
        random_word = random.choice(word)
        print(random_word)
        print("\nThere are", len(random_word)-random_word.count(" "),"letters in this word")
    return random_word


def gethiddenWord():

    import re
    guess = getRandomWord().lower()
    guessed = re.sub(r"\S", "-", guess)
    print("\n\t\t\t-----------------------------------------------")
    print("\t\t\tRULES")
    print("\t\t\t-----------------------------------------------")
    print("\n\t\t\tPlease Guess one letter(a-z) at a time!")
    print("\n\t\t\tIf you want to guess the word, please enter '0'")
    print("\n\nThe word is : ",guessed)
    return guess,guessed
def checkValidGuess():
    if len(guessword)==1 and guessword not in guesslist and guessword not in num:
        return True
    elif guessword in guesslist:
        print("You have already guessed that letter")
    elif guessword in num:
        print("You can only input letter a-z")
        print("Try again")
    elif len(guessword) >1:
        print("You can only guess one letter at a time!")
         print("Try again")
def checkPlayerWord():
    if guessall == word:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    return checkp
def checkLetterInWords():
    if guessword.lower() in word:
        return True
    elif guessword.lower() not in word and guessword.lower() not in num:
        return False


def gethiddenWord():

    import re
    guess = getRandomWord().lower()
    guessed = re.sub(r"\S", "-", guess)
    print("\n\t\t\t-----------------------------------------------")
    print("\t\t\tRULES")
    print("\t\t\t-----------------------------------------------")
    print("\n\t\t\tPlease Guess one letter(a-z) at a time!")
    print("\n\t\t\tIf you want to guess the word, please enter '0'")
    print("\n\nThe word is : ",guessed)
    return guess,guessed
```

my problem is here:

```
def getGuessedWord():
    global words
    for pos,l in enumerate(word): 
        if l==guessword.lower():

            words= words[:pos] + guessword.lower() +words[pos+1:]




    print(words)
    return words
```

And outside the function

```
 word,words = gethiddenWord()
```

my further code to access function:

```
    choose = input("Enter your choice:")
    readFileWords()
    time =10
    word,words = gethiddenWord()
    count = len(word)-word.count(" ")
    guesslist=[]

 while time !=0 and word:

        print("You have", time, "guesses left.")
        guessword = input("Guess a letter or enter '0''to guess the word: ")

        num = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
        valid = checkValidGuess()
        guesslist.append(guessword.lower())


        if guessword =="0":
            guessall = input("What is the word: ")
            checkp = checkPlayerWord()
            del guesslist[0]
            if checkp == True:
                print("Well done! You got the word correct!")
                break
            elif checkp == False:
                print("Uh oh! That is not the word!")
                time -=1
        elif valid== True:
            checkl= checkLetterInWords()
            if checkl == True:
                time -=1
                print("Well done!",guessword,"is in my word")
                count -= word.count(guessword)
                getGuessedWord()
                countfinish = checkFinish()
                if countfinish == True:
                    break
                else:
                    continue

            elif checkl == False:
                time -=1
                print("Uh oh! That letter is not in my word!")
```

If without global, i cannot solve it. Please help! Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with classes? You could create a class Hangman and place the variable "word" into the __init__(self) section. You could then create an instance of "Hangman" for each individual game and always have instance.words available.

Comment: @offeltoffel Thank you. i'm just new to python. i'm still learning !! could you help me in detail. Thanks!

Comment: can you defined words outside of the method...and pass it as method parameter gethiddenword(word):? getGuessedWord(guess,words):?]

Comment: the best implementation of hangman..is to to create a list full of dash with same size as to the word to be guessed...when the user input a character,you replace in the list where the input has matched with word to guess until maximum guess,you can count that was made correctly

Comment: @VincentHoang: I am missing parts of your code to understand how you access the functions (i.e. how you play the game...e.g raw_input)

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan i had tried but the string of dashes (words) will be reset.For example, the word"apple" when you input "a"at first time it will print"a----" and the second input:"l" it will reset to be "---l-"

Comment: the codes are not complete,i get lost when i am following them,like validGuess and others

Comment: why don't use parameter passing?

Comment: how do you get choose variable?does this code works?

Comment: @eliethesaiyan yes it works but passing parameters and  without using global the code doesn't work . The problem when passing parameters and without using global is the string of dashes (words) will be reset.For example, the word"apple" when you input "a"at first time it will print"a----" and the second input:"l" it will reset to be "---l-" –

Comment: if you keep a copy inside while time !=0 and word: and update it from the userinput it will be there

Comment: Thanks. So now what i got to do is call another name for example : dash_string=words ?. @Eliethesaiyan

Comment: just now i've tried but it doesn't work. Could you explain it in detail or could you help me edit my code?@Eliethesaiyan

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan oh now i can solve it by your way. Thank you !!!